# Why do I get 404 Not Found in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, maven, http-status-code-404

My Spring Boot application sends data through REST API. I connects to many Google Cloud components: google pubsub, mqtt server and google SQL. Since I implemented PUBSUB and MQTT, whenever I send a request from Postman I receive
[image: not found response]

My pom.xml configuration looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>bftConfiguration</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>bftConfiguration</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.1.0</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I also found that request is being served by backend to the point of return, so if backend throws an Exception during request processing, it returns 500 Internal Server error
[image]

Even the record is being inserted to database

```
Hibernate: insert into rfid_reader (antennas, created_at, device_id, duration, freqmhz, is_deleted, is_temporary, mode, population, powerdbm, search_mode, session, updated_at, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This is my controller

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/rfid")
public class RfidReaderController {

final RfidReaderService rfidReaderService;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@GetMapping("/get")
public RfidReaderDTO getRfidReader(@PathVariable UUID id){
    return rfidReaderService.getRfidReader(id);
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@GetMapping("/getByDevice/{deviceId}")
public List<RfidReaderDTO> getAllRfidReaders(@PathVariable("deviceId") String id){
    return rfidReaderService.getRfidReaderOptionsByDevice(id);
}
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@PostMapping("/add")
public RfidReaderDTO addRfid(@RequestBody RfidPostDTO input) throws MqttException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InterruptedException {
    return rfidReaderService.addReaderSettings(input.getDeviceId(),input.getPowerDBm(),input.getFreqMHz(), input.getMode(), input.getSession(), input.getPopulation(), input.getDuration(), input.getSearchMode(),input.getAntennas());
}

}
```

here's stack trace when 500 is returned

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.publish(String, org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage)" because "com.company.bftConfiguration.mqtt.MqttClientConnector.client" is null
at com.company.bftConfiguration.service.RfidReaderService.addReaderSettings(RfidReaderService.java:122) ~[classes/:na]
at com.company.bftConfiguration.controller.RfidReaderController.addRfid(RfidReaderController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at com.company.bftConfiguration.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

and here is the code snippet of that service

```
 public RfidReaderDTO addReaderSettings(
        String deviceId,
        Integer powerDBm,
        Double freqMHz,
        Integer mode,
        Integer session,
        Integer population,
        Integer duration,
        Integer searchMode,
        List<Integer> antennas
) throws IOException, MqttException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InterruptedException {
    Device device = deviceRepository.findDeviceByDeviceId(deviceId);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = Date.getDateWithTimeZone();
    ReaderDefaultOptions readerDefaultOptions = new ReaderDefaultOptions();

    RfidReader reader = new RfidReader();
    reader.setPowerDBm(powerDBm != null ? powerDBm : readerDefaultOptions.getPowerDBm());
    reader.setFreqMHz(freqMHz != null ? freqMHz : readerDefaultOptions.getFreqMHz());

    reader.setMode(mode != null ? mode : readerDefaultOptions.getMode());

    reader.setSession(session != null ? session : readerDefaultOptions.getSession());

    reader.setPopulation(population != null ? population : readerDefaultOptions.getPopulation());

    reader.setDuration(duration != null ? duration : readerDefaultOptions.getDuration());

    reader.setSearchMode(searchMode != null ? searchMode : readerDefaultOptions.getSearchMode());

    reader.setAntennas(antennas != null ? antennas : readerDefaultOptions.getAntennas());
    reader.setDevice(device);
    reader.setCreatedAt(dateTime);
    reader.setUpdatedAt(dateTime);
    reader.setIsTemporary(true);
    rfidReaderRepository.save(reader);
    RfidReaderDTO rfidDTO = RfidReaderDTO.builder()
            .antennas(antennas)
            .duration(duration)
            .freqMHz(freqMHz)
            .isTemporary(true)
            .mode(mode)
            .searchMode(searchMode)
            .population(population)
            .powerDBm(powerDBm)
            .session(session)
            .build();
    String rfidJson = new Gson().toJson(rfidDTO);
    MqttClientConnector connector = new MqttClientConnector();
    MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage("state".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    MqttClientConnector.client.publish("dsa",mqttMessage);
    connector.publishData(rfidJson);
    messagingGateway.sendToPubsub(rfidJson);
    return rfidDT
```

I am not interested in the error, I know why it is being thrown. I want to figure out why response returns 404 when the endpoint exists.

Comment: Spring throws 404 Not Found due to the endpoint does not exist. Are you sure that the endpoint is correct? In any way, something is missing in the mapping of the endpoint.

Comment: Yes the endpoint exist because when the backend throws exception the request returns status 500 Internal server error, it is when the code goes all the way to return section and request is being finished successfully, then 404 is being returned. I even debugged the backend and it shows that request enters the controller and then service

Comment: kindly post your Controller classes. After your update that, 500 is coming ,then you must can see the stack trace as well, why this method threw 500

Comment: I added the controller @mfaisalhyder

Comment: @PrzemekGrabarek, can you add the stack trace, and error logs as well, restart the application, and hit the end point. now go to console and copy the complete stack trace and paste here. so that we can help you better.,

Comment: I provided stack trace @mfaisalhyder

Comment: " because "com.company.bftConfiguration.mqtt.MqttClientConnector.client" is null. @PrzemekGrabarek this variable is null, check why it is null, is it not initialized properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was very silly, and the solution is super simple:

I was using @Controller adnotation in my RfidReaderController which is from springframework.stereotype library. I changed it to @RestController and now it works.
just as follows:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/rfid")
public class RfidReaderController {
...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not agree, the answer is clear and simple, instead of Controller adnotation, you use RestController, since it is the correct adnotation used for spring boot rest controller classes